# Google Chrome not retaining default browser selection in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: google-chrome, default, google

Google Chrome is set being my default browser in System Settings, Details. And is also set as default browser within Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)
I reboot three or four times a day and Google constantly asks whether it should be the default. Bug?

Comment: It's been noted by a few people.  I just set Chrome as default in the settings program, and tell Chrome not to ask me anymore.

Comment: This affects me too. What is the best way to report it as a bug? And where I should do it?

Answer (score -1):

Just click the "Don't Ask Any More" button in Google Chrome, it's a bug that has existed in Chrome for a long time.  I've experienced this with Google Chrome through several versions of both Chrome and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Gerowen - but there is no 'Don't ask any more' option visible. When I click on the 'Make Google Chrome the default browser' nothing happend at all.